# How to create type definition for the React useReducer hook action in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

Let's say we have `userReducer` defined like this:

```js
function userReducer(state: string, action: UserAction): string {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return action.username;
    case "LOGOUT":
      return "";
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown 'user' action");
  }
}
```

What's the best way to define `UserAction` type so it will be possible to call `dispatch` both with `username` payload and without:

```js
dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", username: "Joe"}});
/* ... */
dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
```

If type is defined like this:

```js
type UserActionWithPayload = {
  type: string;
  username: string;
};

type UserActionWithoutPayload = {
  type: string;
};

export type UserAction = UserActionWithPayload | UserActionWithoutPayload;
```

Compiler throws and error in reducer in the "LOGIN" case: `TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'UserAction'.   Property 'username' does not exist on type 'UserActionWithoutPayload'.`

If type is defined with optional member:

```js
export type UserAction = {
  type: string;
  username?: string;
}
```

Then compiler shows this error: `TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

What's missing here? Maybe the whole approach is wrong?

Project uses TypeScript 3.8.3 and React.js 16.13.0.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After hours of digging and experimenting found quite an elegant solution via Typescript `enum` and union types for actions:

```js
enum UserActionType {
  LOGIN = "LOGIN",
  LOGOUT = "LOGOUT"
}

type UserState = string;

type UserAction =
| { type: UserActionType.LOGIN; username: string }
| { type: UserActionType.LOGOUT }

function userReducer(state: UserState, action: UserAction): string {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserActionType.LOGIN:
      return action.username;
    case UserActionType.LOGOUT:
      return "";
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function App() {
  const [user, userDispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, "");

  function handleLogin() {
    userDispatch({ type: UserActionType.LOGIN, username: "Joe" });
  }

  function handleLogout() {
    userDispatch({ type: UserActionType.LOGOUT });
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

No errors or warnings using approach above, plus there is a quite strict contract for action usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
function userReducer(state: string, action: UserAction): any {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return action.username;
    case "LOGOUT":
      return "";
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown 'user' action");
  }
}
```

In this function, you defined return type as a string. But when you pass down UserAction as UserActionWithoutPayload type, the return value should be undefined. These causes differ between your userReducer(...) function return type and real return type as a string and undefined.
To fix this, you can change return type as any.

I hope this answer might be helpful in your work.

Regards.
Lin.

Comment: Please visit this URL for the code test.
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-pare-z89v7

Answer (score 1):

The approach looks ok, the problem is that your reducer has a return type of `string` but if it is passed a `UserActionWithoutPayload` then it might return `action.username` where username is undefined.

So one way to fix it would be to relax your return types:

```
function userReducer(state: string, action: UserAction): string | undefined {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return action.username;
    case "LOGOUT":
      return "";
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown 'user' action");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help, as then the actual usage of the reducer, i.e.:
`const [user, userDispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, "");` gives an error: `No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: string, action: UserAction) => string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.`

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the specific reducer case some more type info by type-casting the action

```js
type UserActionWithPayload = {
  type: string;
  username: string;
};

type UserActionWithoutPayload = {
  type: string;
};

type UserAction = UserActionWithPayload | UserActionWithoutPayload;

function userReducer(state: string, action: UserAction): string {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return (action as UserActionWithPayload).username;
    case "LOGOUT":
      return "";
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown 'user' action");
  }
}

let state = "";
state = userReducer(state, { type: "LOGIN", username: "John" });
console.log("LOGIN", state);

state = userReducer(state, { type: "LOGOUT" });
console.log("LOGOUT", state);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgQQMbAJYHsB2B1DYACwAUBDEAGyzIBMoBeKAbwCgopRIAuKOYRBhwBzANzsoAVwSIcZALYRe-QSPEBfcay7R4SNJlwFiWScHJUa9Jmw47lAoWNabW28LpkHsORrC-oPsakFNR0UAA+-vqBRoREpuahVloAZpI4sb7SSABKELSSqEgAFPxkwEp8jiIANFBkWbx6KFkAlA6qwiwScADuhKhEUCWNhjgAdDptPRwcqGQIUABEADIA8gDiAJIAcsvcEnNQiBDAkrIjYz4NcNGt48EWYbRtEzmyChDixwtLa1t1jAACoHI5zU7nS7LZY-Oa0CCpMiSSjAQ7HOxERBYPpQHAQXEAUUQ2MQJWWMBwAGscDjfAByD70hpZZZtOHqFxuShnaoVaBMGHicqVPwffKFYpkkUQerMTgeXgAnb7eofOSKJUAKSwRBwyyg6nZrFQuDgWB5E2ownJGxVy3qMuNrBlYpkEqKpRlcoVPBWdqBoMNxtNOHNluttsBIIdfMqxqAA)